Sometimes the "printWidth" option in "prettier" is applied, but sometimes it is not
How to reproduce the phenomenon

Install "Prettier - Code formatter" extention in Vscode

write file .prettierrc


{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 400,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true
}

Please remember that I set the "printWidth" option to 400 very well.

write file .vscode/settings.json

{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}

Situation where printWidth option works well
-- write
export default function Page() {
  const menu = [{ name: 'hong', age: 11 }, { name: 'gil', age: 22 }, { name: 'gil' }];
  return <></>;
}

-- after save (auto formatting)
export default function Page() {
  const menu = [{ name: 'hong', age: 11 }, { name: 'gil', age: 22 }, { name: 'gil' }];
  return <></>;
}

Situation where printWidth option not works
-- write
export default function Page() {
  const menu = [{ name: 'hong', age: 11 }, { name: 'gil', age: 22 }];
  return <></>;
}

-- after save (auto formatting)
export default function Page() {
  const menu = [
    { name: 'hong', age: 11 },
    { name: 'gil', age: 22 },
  ];
  return <></>;
}

Why is this happening?

The "printWidth": 400 setting in Prettier specifies the maximum line length before the code is wrapped. It's important to note that this doesn't enforce a fixed line length; rather, it defines the maximum length a line can reach before it wraps. Please refer to the doc.

It does not seem that the printWidth option works how you seem to want it to:

Prettier’s printWidth option does not work the same way. It is not the hard upper allowed line length limit. It is a way to say to Prettier roughly how long you’d like lines to be. Prettier will make both shorter and longer lines, but generally strive to meet the specified printWidth. - Prettier Docs

Within the docs it suggests another way to do what it seems you want and I think that could help. It suggests using ESLint with the max-len option which is shown here.
Let me know if you run into anything :)
